# how do I pass a variable from my custom component a different component

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

In my custom component (Login), I create and set a variable userName, it is bindable:

```
[Bindable] private var userName:String;
userName = txtUsername.text;
```

I need to pass that variable to a different custom component (Overview), here is the code of the viewstack:

```
<mx:ViewStack id="mainViewStack" x="76" y="90" width="800" height="400">
    <components:Login />
    <components:Overview />
</mx:ViewStack>
```

I've searched for a way, but I haven't found one that does the trick.
Thank you.

Comment: From your question, I assume the variable is in the Login-component, and you want to use it in the Overview-component. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set this variable to public:

```
[Bindable] public var userName:String;
```

and then you can pass it like that (supposing userName is a property of `Login`):

```
<components:Login id="login" />
<mx:Label text="{login.userName}" />
```